# Pathfind in runtime with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity, I want an Agent to path-find in a runtime generated scene. Normally, Unity provides a baked solution for path-finding, but I don't know how to implement it in runtime, or whether it is even possible.

How can I path-find in runtime with Unity?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity you can calculate a Path between two points using:

```
private NavMeshPath myPath;

void Start () {
        myPath= new NavMeshPath();

    }

void SetPath() {

NavMesh.CalculatePath(Vector3 sourcePosition, Vector3 targetPosition, int areaMask, NavMeshPath myPath);

}
```

Once you have the NavMeshPath myPath between two points, you can set that path to an agent:

```
NavMeshAgent.SetPath(NavMeshPath myPath);
```

More about this here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.CalculatePath.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMeshAgent.SetPath.html

Comment: @JoseMartinez-Morales You are welcome. If it worked for you, would be nice it you accept my answer

Comment: What button should I press?